# Divide subscribers of Mailchimp-Form into differrent audiences using checkboxes

Tags: html, forms, mailchimp

I'm trying to build a newsletter signup form that is able to divide subscribers into different audiences. Whereas the checkbox serves as a kind of switch.

Group one (that hasn't ticked the newsletter-checkbox) gets sorted into the "Tutorial Audience". 
Group two (that ticked the newsletter checkbox) gets sorted in the "Newsletter Audience".

Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question, it's about an email provider's tools.

Comment: You can do this fairly easily with the Mailchimp API, thus making it a programming question. Not sure how easy it is within the site itself.

Answer (score -1):

You can now make groups to divide your main audience and it's pretty easy on the site, you can follow this tutorial:

https://mailchimp.com/help/combine-audiences-primary-audience-uses-groups/